# How to set window size and position in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to set the VS Code window size and position, either via `settings.json`, though an extension, or by some other mechanism?

In Atom, I can do this in my `init.coffee` file as such:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
    'custom:prepare-for-screencast': ->
        atom.setSize(1280, 720)
        atom.setPosition(37, 50)
```

Then I can call `Prepare for screencast` from the Command palette.

Comment: The github issue is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61838. It's been discussed for a while, but it seems that as of December 2020, still no effort was made to fix the "feature" that apparently performs as intended.

Comment: I find it INCREDIBLE that years after requests like this one, VSC STILL doesn't have this capability, and requests in the VSC "issues" pages, while upvoted by many users, get "locked and limited conversation to collaborators" by vscodebot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not...yet?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

The closest I can find is window.newWindowDimensions, which only takes a few strings that refer to predefined geometries, although 'inherit' could serve you well in the meantime if you prime the pump by closing al your existing sessions, opening one window, sizing it to your liking, then quitting.  Then all your new windows *should* be that size, and Visual Studio Code seems to be very well behaved with respect to resizing, just never close a resized window last, or it becomes your new default!

As for position, there appears to be nothing at all.

Comment: "window.newWindowDimensions": "maximized" worked great for me. I wanted windows to open much larger - the default is way too small to be useful.

Answer (score 53):

in vscode, go to

> settings -> window -> new window -> new window dimension

there you are able to choose the following option to set the default dimensions, if vscode is getting opened:

> inherit || offset || maximized || fullscreen

I prefer to use "inherit", i.e. open vs-code always as large as the previous one.

Comment: 2023 and this is still the best answer. Tks.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: idea is valid for 2024 as well)

Answer (score 18):

1. Start Visual Studio Code.
2. Click on "**File**"
3. Click on "**Preferences**"
4. Click on "**Settings**"
5. Write " `window.newWindowDimensions` " in the search box.
6. Select the value "**inherit**" from the drop down box.

***That's it...!***

Comment: That will restore a full-screen instance, but it will not afaict restore a part-screen instance to its previous size.  I have a 2560x1480 second monitor.  VSC will restore to a full screen view using this method, but if I reduce the size of VSC to 2560x900 (approx.), then close it, the next time I open VSC I get a 1400x900 (approx.) instance, rather than the previous wider instance.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on a Mac, you can use this AppleScript snippet:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Code"
    tell window 1
        set size to {1080, 720}
        set position to {0, 0}
    end tell
end tell
```

Not a general solution, but works well if you only need it when recording screencasts.

Answer (score 3):

One way I found to solve this was by using the Developer Tools Console:

1. Help -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Console Tab
2. Type: `window.resizeTo(1900, 1060);`
3. Press Enter

*Note: Tested on Windows 10, Ubuntu, OSX*

*Sidenote: Ubuntu had some strange behaviour bringing up the menu and developer tools. I had to open the developer tools while maximized, then undock the developer tools, then unmaximize the window, then type the command.*

Comment: Did not work for me, Win10. Nothing happened :(

Comment: Make sure the window is not maximized / full screen mode.

Comment: ok yeah, that changed. Any tricks for setting the width to make VSCode span 2 monitors?  No matter what width I give, it never exceeds 1 monitor width

Answer (score 2):

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
'custom:prepare-for-screencast': ->
        atom.setSize(1280, 720)
        atom.setPosition(37, 50)
```

> Then I can call Prepare for screencast from the Command palette.

This is really a good idea and a good feature to add to VSCode.
More important to me is "atom.setSize(1280, 720)"

Hope someone will be able to port this to VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the following to settings.json is a good programmatical solution.

```
"window.newWindowDimensions": "offset",
```

The comment in the defaultSettings.json file says:

> - inherit: Open new windows with same dimension as last active one.
> - offset: Open new windows with same dimension as last active one with an offset position.

Basically the inherit option opens new windows completely overlapping to the current window, while the offset option opens new windows with around 50 px size of offset (depends on your screen size) from top/left.

I personally prefer "offset" but these two are essentially almost same.

Answer (score -1):

"window.newWindowDimensions": "maximized"